# Hanging text in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I used the solution offered in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224779/8083) to have hanging indents within tables. This works fine with `tabular`. However, I now have to use a `longtable`. Here the *first* paragraph in each cell is **not** hanging anymore. I am not sure why.

**Does anyone have a solution for this problem?**

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
           11pt, 
           BCOR=8.25mm,
           DIV=11]{scrbook}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\dohang}{\hangindent1em\hangafter1 }

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}[c]{
          >{\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\dohang\everypar{\dohang}\raggedright\arraybackslash}\arraybackslash}p{.15\textwidth}
          >{\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\dohang\everypar{\dohang}\raggedright\arraybackslash}\arraybackslash}p{.75\textwidth}}
      \caption{Long table. } \\
      \toprule
       \multicolumn{1}{l}{consetetur} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sadipscing} \\ \midrule

      \endfirsthead
      \multicolumn{2}{c}%
      {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
      \toprule
       \multicolumn{1}{l}{consetetur} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sadipscing} \\ \midrule
      \endhead
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
      \endfoot
      \bottomrule
      \endlastfoot  
      \emph{Lorem ipsum dolor} & 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  \\
      &  \\
      \emph{Lorem ipsum dolor} & 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{table}
    \caption{Tabular. }
    \begin{tabular}{
          >{\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\dohang\everypar{\dohang}\raggedright\arraybackslash}\arraybackslash}p{.15\textwidth}
          >{\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\dohang\everypar{\dohang}\raggedright\arraybackslash}\arraybackslash}p{.75\textwidth}}
      \toprule
       \multicolumn{1}{l}{consetetur} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sadipscing} \\ \midrule
      \emph{Lorem ipsum dolor} & 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  \\
      &  \\
      \emph{Lorem ipsum dolor} & 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \par
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From what I think to see in the longtable source, at the start of the `p{}` entry a strut is inserted before the `>{}` code is executed. This happens in the macro `\LT@startpbox`. That means the paragraph has already started before the `>{}` code is done. Hence, the `\everypar` comes too late for the first paragraph. It can be compensated by adding a `\dohang` in the `>{}`.

In a normal `tabular`, at least in the `array` package, the strut is inserted through an `\everypar`. That's the reason for the `\expandafter` construction in `\everypar`, because that specific `\everypar` value has to be preserved. In a `longtable` this would not be necessary:

```
>{\everypar{\dohang}\dohang\raggedright\arraybackslash}
```

would do the job, as long as `longtable` isn't updated to conform to the `array.sty` way of doing it.

It seems to me that this is a kind of bug. What do you think, @DavidCarlisle?

Comment: Many thanks. You are right. However, you have to add `\dohang \raggedright` to get the desired effect. Otherwise the text gets justified.

Answer (score 1):

Pieter's solution didn't work for me. I found a working one with the help of [Gail Tang](https://arwintcher.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/adventures-in-latex-formatting-part-2/#comment-5), however:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable, array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{>{\hangindent.5cm\hangafter=1\raggedright}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
        Left aligned text with hanging indent & Justified text without hanging indent
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]