# left alignment of longtable - unwanted minimal indent

Tags: longtable

I have a `longtable` which is a tiny bit indented, despite I have set LTleft to zero. The header line of the table "Gedichttitel .." is not aligned with the text above!

[image]

Reading other perhaps related questions did not help so far; for example, it seems that `@` could be useful in this case, but I cannot understand its use nor find documenation (the documenation for the array package seems to technical for me).

The MVE is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=     %161mm:239mm, % increased size to avoid resizing
    6.14in:9.21in,   %format of proof 
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=13,  % textbuecher 11 % textwidth 117
    fontsize=11pt,
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  

\usepackage{booktabs,array,microtype, longtable}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright\fill

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dohang}{\hangindent1em\hangafter1 }


\section{Titel der Gedichte - Titels of Poems}

Da Gedichttitel manchmal im Laufe der Zeit verändert werden 

\begin{longtable}{>{\everypar{\dohang}\dohang\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.7\textwidth} 
        p{0.15\textwidth}
        p{0.05\textwidth} 
        p{0.1\textwidth}}
    Gedichttitel - erste Zeile & Anzahl Zeilen & Buch  & Nummer \\\\
    \endhead 

Abendblick vom Hochstein &  16 &   1 &   1 \\
Abschied &  17 &   1 &  56 \\
Als ich zum ersten Male diesen Narren &  14 &   1 &  30 \\
Als König Salomo beim Tempelbau &  14 &   1 &  50 \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

What needs to be changed to have the table exactly aligne with the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `@{}` before the first column definition:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=     %161mm:239mm, % increased size to avoid resizing
    6.14in:9.21in,   %format of proof 
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=13,  % textbuecher 11 % textwidth 117
    fontsize=11pt,
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  

\usepackage{booktabs,array,microtype, longtable}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright\fill

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dohang}{\hangindent1em\hangafter1 }


\section{Titel der Gedichte - Titels of Poems}

Da Gedichttitel manchmal im Laufe der Zeit verändert werden 

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{}
    >{\everypar{\dohang}\dohang\raggedright\arraybackslash}
    p{0.64\textwidth} 
  r
  r
  r
  @{}
}
    Gedichttitel - erste Zeile & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.12\textwidth}}{Anzahl Zeilen} & Buch  & Nr. \\\\
    \endhead 

Abendblick vom Hochstein &  16 &   1 &   1 \\
Abschied &  17 &   1 &  56 \\
Als ich zum ersten Male diesen Narren &  14 &   1 &  30 \\
Als König Salomo beim Tempelbau &  14 &   1 &  50 \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, add the `@{}` after the last column, and right align column with figures.

Comment: @Sveinung Is it better now?

Comment: I would also suggest removing the extra row (\\) in the table header and replace it with a `\midrule`, and then right aligned the heading of the second column `\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.12\textwidth}}{Anzahl Zeilen}`

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `xltabular`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=     %161mm:239mm, % increased size to avoid resizing
    6.14in:9.21in,   %format of proof 
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=13,  % textbuecher 11 % textwidth 117
    fontsize=11pt,
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  
\usepackage{booktabs,array,microtype,xltabular}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newcommand{\dohang}{\hangindent1em\hangafter1 }

\begin{document}

\section{Titel der Gedichte - Titels of Poems}

Da Gedichttitel manchmal im Laufe der Zeit verändert werden 

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}
  >{\everypar{\dohang}\dohang\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  c c c 
  @{}}
Gedichttitel - erste Zeile & \shortstack{Anzahl\\Zeilen} & Buch  & Nummer \\\\
\endhead 
Abendblick vom Hochstein &  16 &   1 &   1 \\
Abschied &  17 &   1 &  56 \\
Als ich zum ersten Male diesen Narren &  14 &   1 &  30 \\
Als König Salomo beim Tempelbau &  14 &   1 &  50 \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution you propose (which looks exactly what i wanted) but get the error File `xtabular.sty' not found. \usepackage. what is missing?

Comment: @user855443 You have to ensure that you have installed required packages, [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular), [ltablex](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) and [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). Also, you have to have a line `\usepackage{xltabular}` in you documents preamble.

Comment: I tried to install the xltabular from ctan. I unpacked it and copied it to ~/textmf/tex/latex/xltabular. I have now an error `! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.` - what could be wrong? (I have not much experience with installing from ctan).

Comment: What operating system do you have and what TeX distribution? And did _my_  example code works?

Comment: i used eventually the solution from my other question and added @{} for the first column. Thank you for the explanation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499380/161067!

Answer (score 0):

Your table can also be build using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex). However, the `\dohang` command requires modification of [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) left aligned cells. You need to encapsulate the text in a `parbox` of same width as the column width. Therefore, I have defined a new command, `\colbox`, where I also include the `dohang` and `raggedright` commands. The parbox's width is calculated using the same formula as I used when calculating the column width, less right and left padding (side bearing):

```
\newcommand{\colbox}[1]{\parbox{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*19-\cals@paddingL-\cals@paddingR\relax}{\raggedright\dohang #1}}
```

Each of the cells in `column 1` need this modification. If you disagree regarding the rules after the table header (the `midrule`), it is easily removed.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=     %161mm:239mm, % increased size to avoid resizing
    6.14in:9.21in,   %format of proof 
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=13,  % textbuecher 11 % textwidth 117
    fontsize=11pt,
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  

\usepackage{microtype, cals}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % CALS Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent


\newcommand{\dohang}{\hangindent1em\hangafter1 }
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colbox}[1]{\parbox{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*19-\cals@paddingL-\cals@paddingR\relax}{\raggedright\dohang #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Titel der Gedichte -- Titels of Poems}

Da Gedichttitel manchmal im Laufe der Zeit verändert werden
\bigskip

\begin{calstable}[l]  % Left aligned CALS tabular

% Calculate the column width
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*17\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*5\relax}
    }

% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 32

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0pt}   % Outside frame rules
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}  % Rule between header and tabular body
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}             % Inside vertical rules
\def\cals@rs@width{0pt}              % Inside horizontal rules

\def\lp{\ifdim\cals@paddingL=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\fi}

\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Right padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}


% R1H1
\thead{%           The first row are heading and vill be repeated on every page
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{\vfill\colbox{Gedichttitel -- erste Zeile}}\lp
    \alignR\cell{\vfill Anzahl Zeilen}
    \alignR\cell{\vfill Buch}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\vfill Nummer}\rp
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\nointerlineskip
\strut\par}
%R2B1
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{\colbox{Abendblick vom Hochstein}}\lp
    \alignR\cell{16}
    \alignR\cell{1}
    \rp\alignR\cell{1}\rp
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{\colbox{Abschied}}\lp
    \alignR\cell{17}
    \alignR\cell{1}
    \rp\alignR\cell{56}\rp
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{\colbox{Als ich zum ersten Male diesen Narren}}\lp
    \alignR\cell{14}
    \alignR\cell{1}
    \rp\alignR\cell{30}\rp
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{\colbox{Als König Salomo beim Tempelbau}}\lp
    \alignR\cell{14}
    \alignR\cell{1}
    \rp\alignR\cell{50}\rp
\erow

\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: would this work for the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499380/161067 as well?

Comment: @user855443 I have not tested, because I read that question as a different problem. I will check, but I am a little short on time (even though I am on vacation).

Comment: @user855443 I have an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499706/9632)  for your [question 161067](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499380/9632)

Comment: @user855443 I tested [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), but it does not update the running headers. Probably, this is a similar bug described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43409/9632). regarding [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals). So my preliminary answer is: *No, cals does not work for question 161067!*